# UIActivityIndicatorView Not Centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a TableViewController with a UIActivityIndicatorView as a subview while the content loads and it works like it should. The only problem is that I can't get the activity indicator centered on the screen.

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);

loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, 125, 125)];
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2);
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.tableView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: Where does it appear then? Keep in mind that if you use a UINavigationController, the top of self.view is where the navigation bar ends.

Comment: @user2029585 hey try my answer it will solve your problem and inform me after solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe its because your view is of wrong size in xib(say, its for iPhone 5 in xib and you are running it on iPhone 6 ).
So, your height and width calculation is wrong.

Instead, try using

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 17):

Also worth noting, the large indicator seems to be shifted 3 pix left and up. (swift, iOS 9.2.1)

[image]

Comment: This solved it for me. Thank you.   activityView.center = CGPoint(x: containerView.bounds.width/2 + 1.5, y: containerView.bounds.height/2 + 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

**Try the Code :**

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds);
UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]init];
loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2);
loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;

loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.tableView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
[loadingIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: The y coordinate is correct but the x coordinate isn't so the activity indicator is too far right.

Comment: if you tableview is centrally then it works fine.. i have checked it..please try again.

Comment: have you used this line in code...      loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[loadingIndicator setCenter:[self.tableView center]];
```

Comment: I don't see it at all when doing this

Answer (score 0):

try by change this line `loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2);` to `loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;` and add the subview`loadingIndicator` to `self.view`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect, but I think you set frame on basic of self.view and added that indicator on tableview.

so add that indicator on self.view.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the position is not correct horizontally, it may be that view's bounds is still the freedom width from your storyboard.

Try to put your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**. To avoid repeated adding to the view, set the activityObject as a property of this class.

Tejvansh Singh Chhabra's answer is good when you want to center in the screen. Just when generally if you want to position view based on view's frame or bounds, put code after **viewDidLayoutSubviews** stage, or add **constraints** to the view.